# Bootstrap: always fill background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a web application with booststrap, but I have a problem filling the background with a dynamic page.
The page is made by two main columns, the left hand-side column is composed by a menu that can be opened (increasing the height of the column), the right hand-side column is just text. The problem is that, initially the right hand-side column fill all the screen with the background, but if I expand the menu in the left hand-side column the space just created isn't filled by the background.

Little "visual" example:

```
---------------------------
            |
     Menu   |  Text
            |
            |
---------------------------


---------------------------
            |
     Menu   |  Text
 (expanded) |
            |
            ---------------
            | This space
            | is not filled
            | with the background
---------------------------
```

Hope the question is clear enough, thanks in advance!

Comment: Some html/css code and why not a jsfiddle would help us to understand the problem... Hard to answer with just the description.

Comment: Please : for bootstrap : use http://bootply.com/new# ( or another one )

Comment: Just put the background on the row, not on the col-*-

Answer (score 1):

No html/css code to go off of but I'll give it a whack.

Try setting the background of the html or body in your CSS

```
html
{
background-color: black;
}
```

and/or

```
body 
{
background-color: black;
}
```

Hope this helps